# Query to calculate profits in a month

Tags: sql, database, libreoffice-base

I have to tables:

Incomes:

```
| date | incomeAmount |
```

Expenses:

```
| date | expenseAmount |
```

I would like to sum all my incomes in an especific month using: MONTH(date) = ?

I also need to sum all my expenses in this same month

Then subtract to obtain my profit in the month, with an output table similar to that:

```
| Month | TotalIncomes | TotalExpenses | Profit |
```

How can I create a SQL Query in order to do this?
Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT I.Month AS Month,
       I.TotalIncomes AS TotalIncomes,
       E.TotalExpenses AS TotalExpenses,
       I.TotalIncomes - E.TotalExpenses AS Profit
  FROM ( SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE ) AS Month,
                SUM( I.incomeAmount ) AS TotalIncomes
           FROM Incomes
       )  I,
       (
         SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE ) AS Month,
                SUM( E.expenseAmount ) AS TotalExpenses
           FROM Expenses
       ) E
 WHERE I.Month = E.Month
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the aggregated tables.

```
SELECT A.Month, TotalIncomes, TotalExpenses, TotalIncomes-TotalExpenses AS Profit
FROM (MONTH(Date) AS Month, SUM(incomeAmount) AS TotalIncomes
      FROM Incomes 
      GROUP BY MONTH(Date)
      ) A 
INNER JOIN (
      MONTH(Date) AS Month, SUM(expenseAmount) AS TotalExpenses
      FROM Incomes 
      GROUP BY MONTH(Date)
      ) B
 ON A.Month = B.Month
```